# What's the difference for using CALayer and UIView when do iPhone game development?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

For iPhone game development, seems there are very like functions using CALayer and UIView, we can implement our spirit using CALayer or UIView , and animations are usable for them too.  But for coding, there are many difference between CALayer and UIView like object methods and properties etc.  So which is the better choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `UIView` is layer-backed, so you can get a layer reference for any view. If you need it to have UIResponder characteristics (e.g., respond to events), you should probably use a UIView.